# How do I use a part of preg_replace pattern as a variable?

Tags: php, regex, variables, preg-replace

```
function anchor($text)
{
 return preg_replace('#\&gt;\&gt;([0-9]+)#','<span class=anchor><a href="#$1">>>$1</a></span>', $text);
}
```

This piece of code is used to render page anchor.
I need to use the

```
([0-9]+)
```

part as a variable to do some maths to define the exact url for the href tag.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use preg_replace then.  Use preg_match and do something with the results.

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback`](http://de.php.net/preg_replace_callback) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace_callback instead.

In php 5.3 +:

```
$matches = array();
$text = preg_replace_callback(
  $pattern,
  function($match) use (&$matches){
    $matches[] = $match[1];
    return '<span class=anchor><a href="#$1">'.$match[1].'</span>';
  }
);
```

In php <5.3 :

```
global $matches;
$matches = array();
$text = preg_replace_callback(
  $pattern,
  create_function('$match','global $matches; $matches[] = $match[1]; return \'<span class=anchor><a href="#$1">\'.$match[1].\'</span>\';')
);
```